# The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCServices.APIClientError error 1.)

Tags: flutter, xcode, flutter-dependencies

Hello flutter developers, I'm encountering this issue in (xcode), when I perform (product - archive - distribute), that error happens, do you have any idea what's going on??